# Restify backend API, React-native app oauth2 authorization

Tags: react-native, oauth, oauth-2.0, restify

1. We have restify API which has secure and public APIs for the RN app
2. RN app which uses the API. Must have Facebook, LinkedIn, Google login capabilities

Questions:

1. How do I integrate the above logins with the rn app, maybe oauth2?
2. Where should I implement the logic(redirection, calling the authorize URLs of the services) in the RN app or in the backend?
3. After user is authenticated how do I check whether the provided token is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use jwt tokens for this scenario. Your RN app will submit authentication details to your API, the API will authenticate against your relevant store and then sign and generate a json webtoken which is passed back to the RN app.

You will then include the jwt token in all calls to the API. Any calls that result in an invalid token, will return a 401, or possibly 403 status, to your RN app which takes appropriate action to redirect to login etc.

Restify has great support for this and suggest you look at the following npm packages:

[jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

[restify-jwt-community](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-jwt-community)

There are numerous [step-by-step articles](https://medium.com/sean3z/json-web-tokens-jwt-with-restify-bfe5c4907e3c) online to assist with this.

I highly recommend you also read the following article on [vulnerabilities in jwt.](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/)